# Recommend Buy Online Pick up in Store Extension v2.3

Tags: extensions, magento2.3.0, cloud

I'm looking for recommendations for extensions for buy online, pick up in store for Magento Cloud v2.3

Preferably with a Map locator component.  Any recommendations that work with v2.3 cloud greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We went with Magedelight's Store Pickup plug-in.  Out of the box it has great features.  Unfortunately customizing and skinning has been a bit of a hassle due to some non-best practice development.